# Git server side hook not firing - how to check

Tags: git, bash, githooks, rational-team-concert

I'm trying to enforce some policies between a Git and  Rational Team Concert using server side hooks. i.e. pre-receive one, but that hook seems not to be fired.
Even susbsituting given rational hook with a simple bash shell that rename a file this doesn't appear to be executed.
I put the script under /hooks dir with 755 permission, it works fine if executed from the shell.
How can I check where problem is?
Which log can I look at ?

This is the simple shell I'm trying to execute as pre-receive hook

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
# (c) Copyright IBM Corporation 2014. All Rights Reserved.
# 
#  Note to U.S. Government Users Restricted Rights:  
#  Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule 
#  Contract with IBM Corp. 
#
#

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IFS=' '

date >> /tmp/test.txt
#mv /tmp/ss/daeseguire.txt /tmp/ss/eseguito.txt
exit 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve], so that we could help you better!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm a newbie here.
I've modified the original question:

Comment: simsabat: Did you solve the issue? I have the more or less similar problem. I can not check the hook is run or not

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that a `pre-receive` hook is a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).

That means, if you have a local git repo nested within your RTC sandbox (which is the local checkout of an RTC repo workspace), that local Git repo will *not* execute a `.git/hooks/pre-receive` script.

If you have setup the [RTC-Git integration](https://hub.jazz.net/clmhelp/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html&scope=null), then the official documentation is "[Configuring Git and Gerrit server-side hooks](https://hub.jazz.net/clmhelp/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html&scope=null)".
But it supposes the [configuration step](https://hub.jazz.net/clmhelp/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html&scope=null) is done and working, which means you can look at the Apache log to see if there is any clues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
First of all I'm using git with a remote repository, on a Linux RHEL with Apache,  repository is under 

/var/www/html

Comment: then, I'm not still firing RTC given hooks, since I cannot even fire a simple shell hook.

Comment: @simsabat are you using the official RTC-Git integration?

Comment: I would like to, but how can I use a complex hook like the RTC one if I'm not able to let the system execute a single one?

Comment: @simsabat I agree: let's debug that first: when you do a git push, are you pushing to that specific remote Git repo through your Apache you mentioned before?

Comment: I'm pushing from my local copy of git repo towards remote git repo that is located under folder:

/var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

this is the output of my push operation:

> $ git push --verbose Getting pack list Fetching remote heads...
>   refs/   refs/tags/   refs/heads/ updating 'refs/heads/master'   from
>   decabae30c2b8cfac8e2795a1da342ce9e22ec12   to
>   6e583f66c4410fd0e2ee18ee491236f16d05f64b
>       sending 5 objects
>       sent 707de30e348030620f1e49d14f4e7cf108e305c9
>       sent 4d9de1b3a723b21d6855354dd6867c72e4853b43
>       sent 6e583f66c4410fd0e2ee18ee491236f16d05f64b
>       sent a9e64e39116bc7abd9af2c5eeaa071e4a4243294
>       sent 845de842759b28a53651c86073afa9ce6e30577e
>       done Updating remote server info Pushing to http://172.24.113.41/pico2.git/ To http://172.24.113.41/pico2.git/
>   decabae..6e583f6  master -> master updating local tracking ref
>   'refs/remotes/origin/master'

Comment: no errors appear in apache access_log and error_log